# Avoid that value gets 'overwritten' in arraylist

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I am trying to save some values in a arraylist but somehow they all get overwritten ending up with only 1 value in the arraylist (200).

```
final String[] titles = new String[urls.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
        ArrayList<Integer> valuesList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            valuesList.add(page.getTopicCount()); // returns 4 values (50,100,150,200)
                System.out.println("Element: " + valuesList.toString()); 
                    // returns only value 200
    }
```

---

The code `page.getTopicCount()` returns the 4 values in 1 line (50 100 150 200) only the last one (200) gets added to the arraylist but i am trying to find a way to save them all 4 seperately.

What options do i have? (SharedPreferences, saving to file, do i have to build another loop)?

I already did some research and ended up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences) page but i don`t know if this will work.

Ps: the 4 values are constantly changing, thus it is no option to add them as:

```
valuesList.add("50");
valuesList.add("100");
etc..
```

Edit:
getTopicCount is part of a Saxparser class, see below code snippet:

```
public void endElement(final String uri, final String localName, final String qName)
        throws SAXException {
//

} else if (localName.equals("topiccount")) {
        in_topiccount = true;
        sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
//

  else if (localName.equals("topiccount")) {
        in_topiccount = false;
        forumPage.setTopicCount(Integer.parseInt(sb.toString())); //returns 50 100 150 200
        sb = null;
    }
// 
}
```

Comment: what `page.getTopicCount()` and a return type?

Answer (score 2):

Inside the for loop, you are initializing the *valuesList* ArrayList. So each iteration, you create a new ArrayList and add one element to it and then discard it. As a result, at the end you only have a reference to the last ArrayList you created, which can only have 200 in it.

Presumably what you want to do is something like:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> valuesList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
            valuesList.add(page.getTopicCount()); // returns 4 values (50,100,150,200)
  }    
  System.out.println("Element: " + valuesList.toString());
```

Edit: Essentially, create the ArrayList once, and then insert elements into it in the for loop.

Comment: Hi La Dee Dah, already tried that same issue, 200 gets only added, rest overwritten.

Comment: Are you sure that title.length and page.getTopicCount() are returning what you want? http://ideone.com/sNIeSH shows how this code would work if those two aren't some crazy values.

Comment: This to me means the problem is twofold; 1: your for loop is incorrect. 2: If, as you say, fixing the for loop still gives you incorrect output then either titles or page.getTopicCount() are not behaving as you want.

Comment: Hi titles.length = 4, so it loops 4 times, the values i want are also 4.
getTopicCount returns these 4 values but 1 one single stroke.
It`s kind of a 'stream' which ends when all 4 pages are parsed.

Comment: Sorry, you say "page.getTopicCount() returns the 4 values in 1 line". What do you mean by 'in 1 line'? If I do System.out.println(page.getTopicCount())) just once in the beginning, what is the output? '50', right?

Comment: No problem, no, it is 200.
I see it like that 50 gets added, then 50 gets replaced by 100, then 100 replaced by 150 ending up with the last value 200.
As it said it`s kind of stream.

Comment: Ah, so the issue is not in the loop at all- the problem is entirely in getTopicCount. From what you say, it always returns the last entry. Unfortunately I can't help without getTopicCount's code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68112/discussion-between-la-dee-dah-and-bjorn).

Comment: i need your help, are you there?